# When a layer cross-cuts two projections and have calculate length

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, australia

I have a shapefile which cross cuts between two projections. I am wanting to calculate length and do alot of anaysis with this shapefile. Breaking up the shapefile over each projection and calculating it will not work due to the amount of analysis i have to do.

Is it fine to use either or projection to calculate length? Or should i make a new projection?

[image: length to measure across two projections]

Comment: There aren't really any projections that just stop working like this. Personally, if they're both at the effective edge of a projection, I'd reproject *both* to a new, more appropriate projection. What that might be is far too subjective for StackExchange.

Comment: Is this two different UTM zones? These are not really separate projections. My advice would just be to pick one and use it for your project

Answer (score 2):

My answer presumes you won't need *control survey* accuracy level.

Are you working with UTM zones? If so, you are fine to calculate length, because you are between two UTM zones. Just pick one and perform your calculations.

The scale factor along the UTM zone boundaries is 1.000. That means the distortion, along the boundary, is virtually null. Therefore, in the surroundings of the edges of UTM Zones the distortion is smaller than the distortions at the central portion of the UTM zones:

> "The central meridian in each UTM zone has a scale factor of 0.9996,
> which means that measurements along it fall short of true scale by 4
> units in 10,000 (or 1 unit in 2,500). This is the maximum scale error
> anywhere within the zone and is the accuracy standard that the system
> was designed to meet." Source: [geo.hunter.cuny.edu](http://www.geo.hunter.cuny.edu/%7Ejochen/gtech201/lectures/lec6concepts/Map%20coordinate%20systems/UTM%20and%20UPS.htm#:%7E:text=The%20central%20meridian%20in%20each,system%20was%20designed%20to%20meet.)

Comment: Thank you, that makes senses. I am using the projected coordinate system GDA94 Zone 55 and 56 but assuming its the same.

Comment: I believe you can pick any of them. The differences in terms of length will be pretty small.

Answer (score 1):

One of the first projects I worked on was for Port Pirie in South Australia which spans two zones. I was told that as long as I did not have data that went more than half a degree into the second zone it was fine to false it into the first.

I have used that as my rule of thumb for dealing with data spanning UTM/AMG/MGA zones ever since.